# Detaching EBS Volumes (in LVM) take a lot of time

Tags: amazon-ec2, raid, lvm, amazon-ebs, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 Instance(EBS Backed-root partition) with EBS volumes configured via LVM.
I have formatted it as ext4 and can mount it to store data etc.

Now i want take a snapshot of the root partition, hence in that case i go and detach the other non-root EBS volumes (configured in LVM).

Here a regular detach does not work, and i have "force" detach almost always.

Although, i another similar setup with RAID instead of LVM and there after stopping RAID, i can easily detach.

The whole setup is running Ubuntu Maverick 10.10

Please assist me in the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to disable the volume group with `vgchange -a n vgname` before you call the EBS detach API

Answer (score 2):

Disabling a VG , with active LV's will not work.

You should first disable all LV's inside the VG and only after that you can disable the VG.